# Autorelease/Assign Comprehension

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, properties, autorelease, assign

Okay, I really use autorelease/asign lots but I got a problem right now that I don't get. It's probably quite obvious why it isn't working but I'd really like you to explain it to me.

So I've got a UIViewController that I initialize like that:

```
controller = [[[LBLogInViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LBLogInViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

Afterwards, I set it a property (nonatomic, assign) :

```
controller.settingsViewController = self;
```

Why does that property not last? The value I set is the superview's controller so it won't be released. It obviously works with (nonatomic, retain) but I'd like to know why assign doesn't work here.

Comment: Are you doing controller.settingsViewController = self in the same method as the alloc?

Comment: Are you using "controller =" or "self.controller ="? How is controller declared in your header file?

Comment: Yep, right after the initialization.

Comment: After the controller is initialized, I set it as a property "self.contentViewController = controller", which is nonatomic, assign.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your @synthesize, @property and settingsViewController ivar has no spelling mistakes (exactly the sames).

Comment: Nope, it doesn't get dealloced.

Answer (score 0):

If *controller* is declared as (nonatomic, retain) and you use "controller =" instead of "self.controller =", you will not be incrementing the retain count because you are bypassing the setter and going straight to the instance variable.

Comment: didn't see my comment? I initialize it first and set the property using the setter.

Comment: can you post the header files showing how controller and settingsViewController are declared?